# 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, postman

I am trying to configure my POSTMAN as per the below article 
https://gortonington.com/introduction-to-making-api-calls-to-sfmc-from-postman/

But I am facing the Error - **405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.**

I verified the below,
1) A valid "accessToken" is set. [confirmed by making a REST API]
2) All Environment variables are set correctly.
3) Set header variable, SoapAction: Retrieve

Code below for reference,

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Retrieve</a:Action>
      <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:7e0cca04-57bd-4481-864c-6ea8039d2ea0</a:MessageID>
      <a:ReplyTo>
         <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
      </a:ReplyTo>
      <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">{{soapEndPoint}}</a:To>
      <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{accessToken}}</fueloauth>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>Subscriber</ObjectType>
            <Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>
            <Properties>EmailAddress</Properties>
            <Properties>Status</Properties>
            <Filter xmlns:q1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xsi:type="q1:SimpleFilterPart">
               <q1:Property>SubscriberKey</q1:Property>
               <q1:SimpleOperator>equals</q1:SimpleOperator>
               <q1:Value>0032E00002QV2wMQAT</q1:Value>
            </Filter>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the documentation you linked suggests, the action is a POST (check the upper left dropdown).

[image: post configuration sample]

When you see an "http verb" error, it is likely that you are using the wrong verb (such as using GET instead of POST).

You can read more about [HTTP verbs on the Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods).

Comment: Hi @Renato , I confirm that I am using the POST method and still receiving this ERROR. screenshot FYI...https://pasteboard.co/IMiY1t4.png ... Please advise.

Comment: @VishalKumarCV what's the endpoint you are trying to hit? the `{{soapEndpoint}}` variable.

Comment: Wow!!! Finally thanks @Renato for helping me to debug the exact reason... Yes you are right it was the **ENDPOINT** URL which was wrong.... I was trying to hit *https://xxxxxxxxxx.soap.marketingcloudapis.com* but I must have used **https://xxxxxxxxxx.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx**

Comment: @VishalKumarCV This is a good point, I need to make sure to note in my article that `/Service.asmx` needs to be appended on the returned SOAP endpoint from SFMC.  I apologize for not including this previous. I will update shortly. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Update made to the article and I gave credit to both of you for the help in making it more comprehensive. (https://gortonington.com/introduction-to-making-api-calls-to-sfmc-from-postman/)

Comment: @VishalKumarCV good to know that it helped. Remember to flag the answer as accepted it it solved your issue.

Comment: @RenatoOliveira sure.. Done.. I have marked the answer as accepted.

Comment: @Gortonington Welcome! and once gain thanks for creating this one more USEFUL article, which would help a lot who are preparing the Marketing Cloud Developer Certification, as a hands-on experience.

Answer (score 0):

its just need to add this code in webconfig in Host of you application

```
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
         <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
      </modules>
```

Comment: Is this an answer to _this_ question? If so, some additional details would be helpful.